# How to call a function from another workbook module

Tags: excel

I would like to call a function (from WorkbookA) from another excel workbook module (WorkbookB). My intention was to make WorkbookB as a library so other excel workbooks could just call from it. Then I can just update the function just in one workbook instead of updating several others too when updates is needed.

I'm trying to call the function "Gain" from WorkbookB using Application.run as follows, but keep getting "error compile error: argument not optional" at the Topo argument:

```
'Public Function Gain1()

Gain1 = Application.Run("WorkbookB.xls!Gain", Ant, G, Topo)

End Function
```

The function I'm calling from WorkbookB basically something like this:

```
Function Gain (Ant, G, Topo)
  D = 10 ^ ((G - 7.7) / 20)

  Topo1 = Abs(Topo)
  PMin = 100 / D
  If PMin < 1 Then PMin = 1   

Select Case UCase(Ant)
...
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It appears to work for me, what values are you actually passing to the function?

Comment: It works for me too. Are you sure the referenced workbook is open and of "xls" format? If the workbook is closed you will need to specify the path.

Comment: @norie sorry just realised the example i gave does not have the function for "Gain". it actually passes a value of Ant, G and Topo to the Gain formula which can be found in WorkbookB.  Anyway i found out why I'm getting the error, it's because the "Topo" variable is also exist in another module of WorkbookA, if i change the variable name, it is ok. However, it still does not return the value for "Gain" formula in WorkbookB, not sure what i missed.

Comment: Could you update your original post with the new details/code?